# Filebeat running on a windows machine, harvester not reading file - also not connecting to Kafka

Tags: filebeat

Filebeat running on a windows machine. Harvester not reading file and not connecting to kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. I didnt mention the filename extension. after that it worked. Thanks.